# Change http://example.com/wp/ to http://example.com/ using RewriteRule in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to change my url from http://example.com/wp/ to http://example.com/. I am using wordpress so the current .htaccess is inside the /wp/ folder.

I have tried this condition `RewriteRule ^/$ ^/wp/$ [L]` but it doesn't work and it throws an error of `500 Internal Error`.

This is the current code of www/wp/.htaccess .

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I expect that the url should be http://example.com/ but currently it is http://example.com/wp/.

Comment: So what does your http server's error log file show what the actual issue is? A rewriting loop?